# custom layout for all categories page magento

Tags: magento, static, block, categories

I want to display subcategory images on category page over products.
1.  I have created category_listing.phtml with custom code to show subcategories
2. Created a static block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/navigation/category_listing.phtml"}}
```

On category display setting I have selected 'static block and products'.
say i have three categories
category 1
category 2
category 3

if i select static block for one category only perfect but if i call static block in more than one category it shows wrong subcategories unless i delete cache everytime.
Is there any step i am missing, plz reply considering i am new to magento

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open File :app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
And add the the below code :

```
<div class="category-grid-new">
    <?php $_columnCount = 4;?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="sub-category">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0):?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>">
                        <div class="category-img"><img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl() ?>" alt="" width="100px" height="100px"/></div>
                        <div class="category-name"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName()) ?></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, can we use code through static block to use only with specific categories not all categories??

Comment: Please use the given link for your solution. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vkbroR4uj8xldTs9pa3rDNtY4v_QEQf2Xo1ylHStd4o/edit

Comment: Hi Thanks. It gives me the same error as in my question. If I select static block in cat 1 under display setting, it works. When I call the same block in cat 2 it shows me subcategories of category 1 unless I delete cache. But after deleting cache it shows subcategory of 2 in category 1, inshort after calling this block in more than one categories it doesnt show right subcats for respective cats, you have to delete cache everytime to see right subcategories of current category. Though your code in view.html works perfect, may be i have to filter by cat id there.

Answer (score 2):

**1. For Custom category menu navigation in Magento**

**The layout**
Open `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` or your theme’s equivalent.
Place the following code under default tag:

```
<reference name="right">
     <block type="core/template" name="catalog.sidenav" template="page/custom.phtml" before="cart_sidebar"/>
</reference>
```

Create `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/custom.phtml` with the following content:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
        Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
        foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
    ?>
            <li>
                <strong><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></strong>
                <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
                <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>
                    <ul>

                        <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                            <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                            <?php $categoryGrandchildren=$_categoryChild->getChildren(); ?>
                            <li>
                                <?php
                                    $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                    echo '&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryChildModel->getProductCollection()->count() . ')</a>';
                                ?>
                            </li>
                            <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count()) : ?>
                                <?php foreach($categoryGrandchildren as $_categoryGrandchild) : ?>
                                    <?php $_categoryGrandchildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryGrandchild->getId());?>
                                    <li>
                                        <?php
                                            $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                            echo '&emsp;&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryGrandchild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getProductCount() . ')</a>';
                                        ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

You can also insert this template to any other page by coding a layout update or via admin, by inserting this line as content of your CMS page:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/custom.phtml"}}
```

**2.To add category navigation in left sidebar:**

create new file "category_listing.phtml" in your theme at -

```
app/design/frontend/{your_namespace}/{your_module}/template/catalog/navigation/category_listing.phtml
```

Put the following code in it:

```
<div class="block block-category">
   <div class="inside-box">
      <div class="block-title block-category-title">
         <h2><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="block-category-navigation">
         <ul id="category-nav">
            <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>  
            <?php if($_category->name!=""):  ?>    
            <li><?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?></li>
            <?php endif?>  
            <?php endforeach ?>    
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

then call this in the catalog.xml file located in the theme folder -

```
app/design/frontend/{your_namespace}/{your_module}/layout/catalog.xml
```

code:

```
<reference name="left">
   <-- this is new block added by us -->
   <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.categorymenu" after="top.search" template="catalog/navigation/category_listing.phtml"/>

   <block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
   ...
   ...
   ...
</reference>
```

Comment: Hi  Thanks for a detailed reply. It will add code to all categories, Can you please let me know, how to make it work for specific categories, If i have cat 1, 2 ,3 ,4,5 and i want to show subcategories only on cat 3 and cat 5.  Thanks

Comment: after this code <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?> , you have to put condition , <?php if($_category->getId()=='3' && $_category->getId()=='5'){  //subcategory code here }